# Sortmerna Snakefile Key wildcard

Tags: snakemake

Hi I am getting this error in when I try to dry run snakemake and I am not sure how to fix it. I even checked the json file to make sure it was being referenced correctly. I am testing out the script with just one file but I want to be able to run it for over 200 files.

Error:

```
/usr/bin/bash: line 1:  2047 Segmentation fault      sortmerna --ref /data/CEM/buetowlab/controlled_access/rtRNA/mask_HBA_rtRNAs.fasta --reads /scratch/ebogen/transcriptome/samples_156/L0078/CTV17-102_S275_L007_R1_001.fastq.gz --reads /scratch/ebogen/transcriptome/samples_156/L0078/CTV17-102_S275_L008_R1_001.fastq.gz --workdir /scratch/ebogen/transcriptome/samples_156/sortmerna/work_dir/ --idx-dir /scratch/ebogen/transcriptome/samples_156/sortmerna/work_dir/idx_CTV17_102/ --kvdb /scratch/ebogen/transcriptome/samples_156/sortmerna/work_dir/kvdb_CTV17_102/ --readb /scratch/ebogen/transcriptome/samples_156/sortmerna/work_dir/readb_CTV17_102/ --num_alignments 1 --fastx --aligned /scratch/ebogen/transcriptome/samples_156/sortmerna/maskedRNAs/CTV17_102/CTV17_102 --other /scratch/ebogen/transcriptome/samples_156/sortmerna/non_maskedRNAs/CTV17_102/CTV17_102 --paired_in --threads 10
[Thu May 18 14:29:10 2023]
Error in rule fastqc_analysis:
    jobid: 0
    input: /scratch/ebogen/transcriptome/samples_156/L0078/CTV17-102_S275_L007_R1_001.fastq.gz, /scratch/ebogen/transcriptome/samples_156/L0078/CTV17-102_S275_L008_R1_001.fastq.gz
    output: /scratch/ebogen/transcriptome/samples_156/sortmerna/maskedRNAs/CTV17_102.fq.gz, /scratch/ebogen/transcriptome/samples_156/sortmerna/non_maskedRNAs/CTV17_102.fq.gz
    shell:
        sortmerna --ref /data/CEM/buetowlab/controlled_access/rtRNA/mask_HBA_rtRNAs.fasta --reads /scratch/ebogen/transcriptome/samples_156/L0078/CTV17-102_S275_L007_R1_001.fastq.gz --reads /scratch/ebogen/transcriptome/samples_156/L0078/CTV17-102_S275_L008_R1_001.fastq.gz --workdir /scratch/ebogen/transcriptome/samples_156/sortmerna/work_dir/ --idx-dir /scratch/ebogen/transcriptome/samples_156/sortmerna/work_dir/idx_CTV17_102/ --kvdb /scratch/ebogen/transcriptome/samples_156/sortmerna/work_dir/kvdb_CTV17_102/ --readb /scratch/ebogen/transcriptome/samples_156/sortmerna/work_dir/readb_CTV17_102/ --num_alignments 1 --fastx --aligned /scratch/ebogen/transcriptome/samples_156/sortmerna/maskedRNAs/CTV17_102/CTV17_102 --other /scratch/ebogen/transcriptome/samples_156/sortmerna/non_maskedRNAs/CTV17_102/CTV17_102 --paired_in --threads 10
        (one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)
```

Snakefile:

```
import os

configfile: "config_samples.json"

#what the final files will be called. Expand allows for the use of one line that can be filled in with all the options ie sample_name and run
#This should match the output of the final rule you have
rule all:
    input:
        expand("/scratch/ebogen/transcriptome/samples_156/sortmerna/maskedRNAs/{sample_name}.fq.gz", sample_name = config["one_names"]),
        expand("/scratch/ebogen/transcriptome/samples_156/sortmerna/non_maskedRNAs/{sample_name}.fq.gz", sample_name = config["one_names"])

rule fastqc_analysis:
    input:
        r1 = lambda wildcards: os.path.join(config[wildcards.sample_name]["fq_path"], config[wildcards.sample_name]["fq1"]),
        r2 = lambda wildcards: os.path.join(config[wildcards.sample_name]["fq_path"], config[wildcards.sample_name]["fq2"])
    output:
        "/scratch/ebogen/transcriptome/samples_156/sortmerna/maskedRNAs/{sample_name}.fq.gz",
        "/scratch/ebogen/transcriptome/samples_156/sortmerna/non_maskedRNAs/{sample_name}.fq.gz"       
    params: 
        #num_alignments = 1,
        ref_file = "/data/CEM/buetowlab/controlled_access/rtRNA/mask_HBA_rtRNAs.fasta",
        ali = "/scratch/ebogen/transcriptome/samples_156/sortmerna/maskedRNAs/{sample_name}/{sample_name}",
        oth = "/scratch/ebogen/transcriptome/samples_156/sortmerna/non_maskedRNAs/{sample_name}/{sample_name}",
        work_dir = "/scratch/ebogen/transcriptome/samples_156/sortmerna/work_dir/",
        idx_dir = "/scratch/ebogen/transcriptome/samples_156/sortmerna/work_dir/idx_{sample_name}/",
        kvdb = "/scratch/ebogen/transcriptome/samples_156/sortmerna/work_dir/kvdb_{sample_name}/",
        readb = "/scratch/ebogen/transcriptome/samples_156/sortmerna/work_dir/readb_{sample_name}/"
        
    shell:
      "sortmerna --ref {params.ref_file} --reads {input.r1} --reads {input.r2} --workdir {params.work_dir} --idx-dir {params.idx_dir} --kvdb {params.kvdb} --readb {params.readb} --num_alignments 1 --fastx --aligned {params.ali} --other {params.oth} --paired_in --threads 10"
```

config file:

```
{

  "Comment_Sample_Info": "The following section lists the samples that are to be analyzed",
                    
  "sample_names":  ["CTV17_101", "CTV17_102"],
                    
    "CTV17_101": {
        "fq_path": "/scratch/ebogen/transcriptome/samples_156/L0078/",
        "fq1": "CTV17-101_S274_L007_R1_001.fastq.gz",
        "fq2": "CTV17-101_S274_L008_R1_001.fastq.gz"
    },
    "CTV17_102": {
        "fq_path": "/scratch/ebogen/transcriptome/samples_156/L0078/",
        "fq1": "CTV17-102_S274_L007_R1_001.fastq.gz",
        "fq2": "CTV17-102_S274_L008_R1_001.fastq.gz"
    }
}
```

Comment: Segmentation faults are very uncommon problems with `snakemake`. Have you checked whether the command without invoking `snakemake` runs without problems. I.e. run the `sortmerna` command as shown above with the error message `sortmerna --ref <shortend, see the original message> --threads 10` and see if that works.

Comment: @euronion I have run the command by itself and it works and gives the expected output files. It's when I try to write it into a snakemake file that it gives me the problem

Comment: How are you executing snakemake, e.g. through a scheduler (slurm) or interactively?  It could be you aren't requesting enough memory or threads when you run snakemake.